# Openswan L2TP setup to allow admin user access to AWS VPC

Tags: security, amazon-ec2, vpn, amazon-vpc, openswan

I've got an ssh bastion host, but managing the ssh whitelist is annoying, opening ssh to the world is suboptimal. I'd like to tuck a vpn server in front.
Can't get openvpn to stay connected for more than an hour (I'm using 2fa and either openvpn or tunnelblick are apparently ignoring reneg-sec 0 causing hourly re-auth events)

openswan seems like a great option, but I can't get the routing working. I have disabled source/destination checking on the instance and created a route the VPC routing table. I can connect and route traffic northbound, but not to the VPC subnets.
Has anyone successfully done this? I suspect I specifically need help understanding how openswan is handling routing for client nat.

Comment: Note, OpenVPN reneg-sec=0 works to eliminate the 2FA re-auth problem. I was just failing to explicitly re-load my config file on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things to verify. I had a mistake in my iptables config.

For posterity

1. [Disable](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html#EIP_Disable_SrcDestCheck) source/destination check.
2. [Create entry](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Route_Tables.html) in VPC route table to enable routing to the VPN NAT subnet
3. iptables -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -o eth+ -j SNAT --to-source ${PRIVATE_IP}

Reading [this](https://gist.github.com/hwdsl2/9030462#file-vpnsetup-sh) setup script set me straight.